# How to control the size of image attachments in a NSTextView

Tags: image, macos, nstextview

By default, in a NSTextView, image attachments are displayed at their actual resolution. For large images, this results in having only a small portion of the image displayed in the view. This doesn't look good and the user has to do lots of scrolling to enter text after the image.

For example, in the window below, you can't tell much about the image in the text view.

[image: Default image size in NSTextView]

So the question is: how to scale down image attachments, so that they fit in the NSTextView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find a few solutions for this on the internet, based on subclassing `NSTextAttachmentCell`, but by doing so, you lose a number of good behaviors provided *for free* by the NSTextView, like the creation of annotations in an attached image.

Actually there is a much simpler solution: to use a `NSLayoutManager` property named `defaultAttachmentScaling` that does exactly what we want.

In your code, set this property as in:

```
myTextView.layoutManager.defaultAttachmentScaling = NSImageScaleProportionallyDown;
```

and this is it: large images are now scaled to match the width of the text view.
[image: Image size in NSTextView with defaultAttachmentScaling set]

For detailed information on this property, I suggest you read the comments in the header file `NSLayoutManager.h`.

Note for iOS developers: unfortunately, this property is not available on iOS.

Comment: Swift 4: `myTextView.layoutManager?.defaultAttachmentScaling = NSImageScaling.scaleProportionallyDown`

Comment: Thank you for this - it works great! However, I would really have to find a way to set a custom size of the attachment, as I can in UIKit. Is that possible?